# Is there a way to return data with a string like the given query?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I'm coding a search function, with users having a username that you can find by searching. I can get users that completely match the string query, but I want to get all users whose username contains the query string I entered.
Here's what I have so far:

```yaml
paths:
  /user:
    description: get and create users
    get:
      description: Get user
      parameters: 
        # something here to get all users whose name includes the query
        - in: query
          name: studentname
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
            example: Jeffery
      responses:
        200:
          description: Successful!
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/students'
```

Comment: What's your question exactly? If you're asking whether this OpenAPI definition is valid for the "contains" search - yes, it's valid for both "exact match" and "contains" searches. It's up to the backend implementation to control how the parameters are being processed.

Comment: OK thank you very much.
I was wanting to know whether the OpenAPI definition can be used for the contains search